# Word frequency finder

Tags: strings, haskell, functional-programming, reinventing-the-wheel

Challenge: find the top three most frequently used words in a string. Only imports from the `base` package are allowed (source: [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51e056fe544cf36c410000fb))

I'm looking for feedback on (1) readability, and (2) performance

- Was folding the string into "frequency map" a good choice?
- I have several small functions that I compose together. Are these
  abstraction layers helping or hurting readability?
- How are my functions names?
- Does the `base` package have any libraries that would make this code significantly easier to write?
- Could I benefit from using more pointfree style?

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.List
import Data.Function
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe

top3 :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
top3 str =
  let
    wordFrequencyMap = foldr (Map.alter increment) Map.empty (normalizedWords str)
    sortedWordFrequencies = sortBy reverseBySecond (Map.toList wordFrequencyMap)
  in map fst (take 3 sortedWordFrequencies)
  where
    normalizedWords = filter containsAtLeastOneAlphaNumericChar . lowerCaseWords . map isLegalChar
    containsAtLeastOneAlphaNumericChar w = find isAlphaNum w /= Nothing
    lowerCaseWords = map (map toLower) . words
    isLegalChar c = if isAlphaNum c || c =='\'' then c else ' '
    reverseBySecond x y = if snd x < snd y then GT else LT
    increment Nothing = Just 1
    increment (Just x) = Just (x + 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency map is a good way to solve this. A nice trick to generate the frequency map is by creating a list of singleton maps and merging them all together:

```
wordFrequencyMap = Map.unionsWith (+) $ map (\x -> singleton x 1) $ normalizedWords str
```

I think this way is a bit more declarative which is what we aim for in Haskell.

---

You could simplify:

```hs
    containsAtLeastOneAlphaNumericChar w = find isAlphaNum w /= Nothing
```

to

```hs
    containsAtLeastOneAlphaNumericChar = any isAlphaNum
```

At that point you might find it clearer to inline the definition:

```hs
    normalizedWords = filter (any isAlphaNum) . lowerCaseWords . map isLegalChar
```

---

To sort in descending order, use `Down` from `Data.Ord`, this will reverse the ordering of whatever is passed into it, e.g. `Down 1 > Down 2` is True.

```hs
    sortedWordFrequencies = sortOn (Down . snd) (Map.toList wordFrequencyMap)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write

```
increment = (<|> (Just 1)) . fmap (+1)
```

You can probably also write

```
reverseBySecond = flip $ comparing snd
```

if you don't mind getting `EQ` for equal pairs.

Comment: I like the use of `<|>`, I've never used it. I'll add it to my toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

i had already answered this from within my http://lynx.browser.org/ unbloated hypertext browser within superfast http://www.washington.edu/alpine/ mail commander but http://stackexchange.com/ does not behave like written from humans for humans and rather unfortunately insists on a robot captcha unsolvable on a braille typewriter.

i will recreate my first intuitive answer which goes more lambda calculus and less hoare calculus than your code to try

```
top3=map head.take 3.reverse.sortBy(comparing length).group.sort.words
```